# returning a list of players based on position

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a method that creates a set of 6 objects and has variables assigned to them, including name, team, position, etc. 
I need a method that can search the array of objects and only display the ones with a chosen variable(position).The project requires that I display a list of only the players that have a certain position. So for this if the chosen position was "QB" it would display "Eli Manning" "Tom Brady" "Derek Car" with their stats accompanying.

```
//constructor creating 6 players
public NFLPlayerManager(){
    NFLPlayer x = new NFLPlayer("Eli Manning", "New York Giants", "QB", 21, 77, 72, 170, 0, 160, "TCU");
    playerList.add(x);
    NFLPlayer y = new NFLPlayer("Tom Brady", null, "QB", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
    playerList.add(y);
    NFLPlayer z = new NFLPlayer("Josh Kline", null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
    playerList.add(z);
    NFLPlayer a = new NFLPlayer("Derek Carr", null, "QB", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
    playerList.add(a);
    NFLPlayer b = new NFLPlayer("Rob Gronkowski", null, "TE", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
    playerList.add(b);
    NFLPlayer c = new NFLPlayer("James White", null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
    playerList.add(c);
}
```

Comment: Please share some code. It's impossible to answer a question phrased like this.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: It's very difficult to answer this question in its current state without guessing. Please improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void showPlayerByPosition(String position)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < playerList.size(); i++)
    {
        //now lets grab the NFLPlayer's position with a getter and compare it to the given string in our parameter
        if(playerList.get(i).getposition().equals(position))
        {
            //then print the NFLPlayer
            playerList.get(i).showPlayer(); //Note i making up the name for the print function
        }

    }
}
```

Now you can call the function like so

```
showPlayerbyPosition("QB")
```